# Why Entity Framework right pads SP CHAR (6) parameters to 8002 spaces?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

Using EF6, VS2015, EDMX, Database First

I call a stored procedure using a function import and it is working fine on the surface.

However, when I use SQL Server profiler, I notice that EF right pads all `CHAR(2)` or `CHAR(6)` parameters with spaces to exactly **8002** characters!

A `CHAR(6)` must be exactly 6 characters, not 8002.

Why is that and how can I prevent this unnecessary padding?

Comment: It sounds like EF thinks (wrongly) that the column size is `VARCHAR(MAX)`.  The max size of a VARCHAR column in SQL is 8000 characters + 2 for storage.

Comment: @Amy Within the EDMX designer, the stored procedure parameter type is CHAR

Comment: I was having the same problem in EF 6.1.1. Installed 6.1.3 and the problem is not fixed.

Comment: @adrianz, I gave up and coded the SP call with classic ADO.NET. Works very well and I have much control over SP parameters.